# Amazon MWS Getting Started

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I recently looked into Amazon MWS and wanted to develop for it. I do have a seller account and downloaded the the given files for java. I included all the .jars and opened the `ListOrderItemsSample.java`. There I set the `sellerId`, `mwsAuthToken`and an `amazonOrderId`. Looking further into the code I also copied the `MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersSampleConfig.java`into my project and set all the necessary Strings there. I did not change anything else. The problem is in runtime the program throws an exception.

Following the console output, where `Test.java` the `ListOrderItemsSample.java`file is:

```
Service Exception:Exception in thread "main" 
Message: null
StatusCode: 0
ErrorCode: null
ErrorType: null
com.amazonservices.mws.orders._2013_09_01.MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersException
    at com.amazonservices.mws.orders._2013_09_01.MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient$RequestType.wrapException(MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient.java:143)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsConnection.call(MwsConnection.java:429)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.orders._2013_09_01.MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient.listOrderItems(MarketplaceWebServiceOrdersClient.java:75)
    at Test.invokeListOrderItems(Test.java:44)
    at Test.main(Test.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsConnection$ServiceEndpoint.<init>(MwsConnection.java:102)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsConnection.getServiceEndpoint(MwsConnection.java:398)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsConnection.newCall(MwsConnection.java:687)
    at com.amazonservices.mws.client.MwsConnection.call(MwsConnection.java:420)
    ... 3 more
```

Did I miss to set anything or what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to definitively say without seeing your config but it sounds like you didn't set all of the required parameters.

For the orders API, it's required that you set the seller id, access key id, secret key and order id.

I'd use the [MWS Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) to get an idea of what the required request parameters are for each API.

Comment: Using the scratchpad I instantly realized where my problem is, which is very stupid. I did not realize, and also not read anywhere on the Amazon API that I would need an AWS account to use MWS. I will create an account and see if it then works.